# iOS Invert Colors on Application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, gpuimage

I'd like to invert all colors in my application like Settings > Accessibility > Invert Colors. Is there a way to make this stuff in a programmatically way in iOS such using CALayer or Filters like GPUImage or CoreImage?

Comment: Nope, I'm still looking the solution of the problem...